# Firebase query help for react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm kinda new to firebase & react-native but I need a little help with a query I have to do for my project.

So let's say I have 2 tables

```
Posts:{postID(key), posterID, description}
Likes:{likeID(key), postID, likerID}
```

so the relationship between these two tables is on postID

Is there a way to count all likes for each Post and return top 10 with most likes? I know that this process can't be all on server side so I'm fine with any solutions really.

I think this is the query to count likes for one post:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/likes`)
        .orderByChild('postId').equalTo(postID)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
            const likesCount = snapshot.count;

        })
```

Comment: if you need any sort of complex queries, I would strongly recommend not using firebase, as you'll be building workarounds all day long

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to count all likes for each Post...?

Firebase has no built-in aggregation queries. You'll typically either do this client-side, or through Cloud Functions, and write the count into each post. You'd then order on that "count property" to return the posts with the most likes.

Also see:

- [In Firebase, is there a way to get the number of children of a node without loading all the node data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load) (showing how to atomically increment a counter)
- this [sample of counting child nodes using Cloud Functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/child-count)
- [Is the way the Firebase database quickstart handles counts secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure) (a discussion about securely counting likes)
- [Aggregate values coming from firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568734/aggregate-values-coming-from-firebase-database)